# How to train a yolov8 model on only once class of many?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, object-detection, yolov8

I have a database that I can (and did) train a model to detect objects. But I want to use the exact same database to TRAIN one model to only detect one object.

So I need to train a model on the same database, but it has to ignore all other classes. Just changing .yamal file, to have only the name of the class I need won't work, since the yolov8 assigns the index in .yamal file to the one in .txt.

Is there a way to ignore all other classes when TRAINING, simply somehow in .yaml file, or will I have to write a script that will delete all other classes from my database?

Comment: You have to keep only the relevant class objects in .txt labels and also change the .yaml  file for this 'new' dataset. Of course, you don't have to delete the original data permanently, just make a copy of the original yaml and label folders for future use. Also, you can use your already trained model to detect only the relevant classes: `results = model.predict(source, classes=[1, 4, 22])`